# ECONNRESET error when installing with npm while behind a proxy

Tags: npm

I am getting this error when trying to install packages using `npm` :

[![Error Message][1]][1]

From what I read, it is about not being able to connect to https://registry.npmjs.org/

I tried using `npm config set registry` but it did not solve the problem.

What could be stopping this from working?

BTW, I found a solution. The solution is to switch the internet. I suppose this occurs because of dorm's connection. Thanks for everything
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFdpS.png

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, using some VPN? If you `curl ifconfig.me` what does it output, is it your IP? Could you also share what versions of `node` and `npm` you are using?

Comment: Can you please share the exception and some more details about your issue?

Comment: @Piotr Ostrowski Yes, I am behind a proxy, but not using any VPN. I did the search. curl ifconfig.me is 193.140.111.23 and my IP is 192.168.56.1 which means they don't match. My node version is 18.1.0 and my npm version is 8.11.0

Comment: @GravityAPI My exception occurs when I try to install something using npm. This happened for ganache, too. Whenever I use it, proxy error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy issue like when your company is using Artifactory as NPM registry, you can try (work on Windows):

```bash
cd ~ # go to user directory
touch .npmrc # create the file if don't exist
```

Edit the file and add:

```
registry https://artifactory.your-domain.fr/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/=
registry=https://artifactory.your-domain.fr/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/
# strict-ssl=false # you may need that if you company install an intermediate certificate on your machine (they spy on you HTTPS ;)).
```

Where `your-domain.fr` is to be replaced.

Comment: I am not working for a company, at least right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below?

```bash
npm --without-ssl --insecure i ethers
```

If you know the details of the proxy you are using:

```bash
npm config set proxy http://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but the code above did not work. Also, I am not using any proxy. Do you have any idea what this is all about?

Comment: Right, you could probably try using a proxy or turning off the VPN for the time of installation.